# function return varray error

Tags: function, plsql, varray

I keep getting a error when i run this code, What wrong with the code?

```
create or replace function f_vars(line varchar2,delimit varchar2 default ',')
return line_type is type line_type is varray(1000) of varchar2(3000);
sline varchar2 (3000);
line_var line_type;

pos number;
begin
sline := line;
for i in 1 .. lenght(sline)
loop

pos := instr(sline,delimit,1,1);
if pos =0 then
line_var(i):=sline;
exit;

endif;
string:=substr(sline,1,pos-1);
line_var(i):=string;
sline := substr(sline,pos+1,length(sline));

end loop;
return line_var;
end;
```

LINE/COL ERROR

---

20/5     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "LOOP" when expecting one of
         the following:
         if

22/4     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting
         one of the following:
         end not pragma final instantiable order overriding static
         member constructor map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Stack Overflow isn't really a de-bugging service](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128548/what-stack-overflow-is-not/135066#135066).

However, I'm feeling generous.

You have spelt `length` incorrectly; correcting this should fix your first error. Your second is caused by `endif;`, no space, which means that the `if` statement has no terminator.

This will *not* correct all your errors. For instance, you're assigning something to the undefined (and unnecessary) variable `string`.

---

I do have more to say though...

I cannot over-emphasise the importance of code-style and whitespace. Your code is fairly unreadable. While this may not matter to you now it will matter to someone else coming to the code in 6 months time. It will probably matter to *you* in 6 months time when you're trying to work out what you wrote.

Secondly, I cannot over-emphasise the importance of comments. For *exactly* the same reasons as whitespace, comments are a very important part of understanding how something works.

Thirdly, always explicitly name your function when ending it. It makes things a lot clearer in packages so it's a good habit to have and in functions it'll help with matching up the `end` problem that caused your second error.

Lastly, if you want to return the user-defined type `line_type` you need to declare this _outside your function. Something like the following:

```
create or replace object t_line_type as object ( a varchar2(3000));
create or replace type line_type as varray(1000) of t_line_type;
```

Adding whitespace your function might look something like the following. This is *my* coding style and I'm definitely not suggesting that you should slavishly follow it but it helps to have some standardisation.

```
create or replace function f_vars ( PLine in varchar2
                                  , PDelimiter in varchar2 default ','
                                    ) return line_type is 

   /* This function takes in a line and a delimiter, splits
      it on the delimiter and returns it in a varray.
      */

   -- local variables are l_
   l_line varchar2 (3000) := PLine;
   l_pos number;

   -- user defined types are t_
   -- This is a varray.
   t_line line_type;

begin

   for i in 1 .. length(l_line) loop

      -- Get the position of the first delimiter.
      l_pos := instr(l_line, PDelimiter, 1, 1);

      -- Exit when we have run out of delimiters.
      if l_pos = 0 then
         t_line_var(i) := l_line;
         exit;
      end if;

      -- Fill in the varray and take the part of a string
      -- between our previous delimiter and the next.  
      t_line_var(i) := substr(l_line, 1, l_pos - 1);
      l_line := substr(l_line, l_pos + 1, length(l_line));

   end loop;

   return t_line;

end f_vars;
/
```